# Dynamically added row does not post when index is not iterative in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, post, razor

I dynamically added a row in my ASP.NET MVC view. For example if I have 4 rows and delete the 3rd row using jQuery, then my ASP.NET MVC post method only posts back the first 2 rows, because it breaks the index serial.

Name value is like `name="Answers[1].AnswerName"` and next value is `name="Answers[3].AnswerName"`, so it only posts back `Answers[0]` and `Answers[1]`, not `Answers[4]` after the `Answers[2]` which is removed.

What is needed to post all the rows even if the serial is broken?

```
@{
    int i = 0;

    foreach (Answer ans in Model.Answers)
    {
        <tr id="@ans.AnswerID">
            <td style="width:10%">@(i+1)</td>
            <td style="width:60%">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(t => t.Answers[i].AnswerName, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please enter answer
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width:10%">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(t => t.Answers[i].IsCorrect, new { @type = "checkbox", @id = "Answers[" + ans.AnswerID + "].IsCorrect" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(t=>t.Answers[i].AnswerID)
            </td>
            <td style="width:20%">
                <button type="button" style="font-size:10px" onclick="generatenewrow(this)">Add <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
                <button type="button" style="font-size:10px" onclick="deleteNewRow(this)">Delete <i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>

        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your script that dynamically adds or removes from the html table. We need to add a reorder feature.

Comment: function deleteRow(e) {
        debugger;
        var totalRow = $("#tbodyAnswer").find('tr').length;
        if (totalRow > 2) {
            var element = $(e);
            var id = element.closest('tr').attr('id');
            $("#" + id).remove();
        }
        else {
            $("#centralModalSm").modal('show');
            $("#txtMessage").text("Must have two option");
        }

    }

Comment: how to add reorder feature ?

Comment: dude! @akash I am stuck in such situation too. How did you get rid of this prob. What solution you have found? please share it with me.

Comment: @ZiaUrRahman I handle this issue using java script. I didn't use MVC post method. I implement a script which prepare the model iterating through all the tr of that answer table. After that passed that obj in MVC post action method.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution and this is the best solution I think.
[Dynamically add/remove fields from array without breaking it in .net mvc app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64772046/dynamically-add-remove-fields-from-array-without-breaking-it-in-asp-not-mvc-core)

This will help you alot.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but I resolved this issue using iterating all the tr of that answer table and pass that object to my MVC action method using an ajax call. Above solution might be costly because it changes all the table row id whenever some deletion occur.